# Error in sample.int(length(x), size, replace, prob) : invalid 'size' argument ; when i using evaluationScheme

Tags: r, cross-validation, recommendation-engine, recommenderlab

I would like to evaluate my model with the function of the package `Recommenderlab`

```
scheme <- evaluationScheme(UserByProductRRM, method = "cross-validation", k = 10, given =-1 , goodRating = 4)
```

but I don't understand why I have this error

> Error in sample.int(length(x), size, replace, prob) :    invalid
>   'size' argument

Comment: Hi, I got the same error. Did you find what was going on?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps your dataset (UserByProductRRM) has lines with only 0s. You must delete those lines. In *RealRatingMatrix* or *BinaryRatingMatrix* all lines must have at least one 1. Try [rowSums](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/raster/versions/2.6-7/topics/rowSums) function to detect lines with only 0s.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this error seems to be that the dimensions of the sample fraction you want to extract from the data set cannot be calculated. That is, the value of the "size" parameter you specified cannot be calculated. Therefore, I suggest you try to see the "size" parameter from the console. The "evaluationScheme" function refers to the sample function. Sample function cannot calculate "size". An example of this is the following.

```
library(tidytext)
library(tidyverse)
library(dplyr)
data("iris")
df_iris<-as.data.frame(iris)
train<-sample(1:nrow(df_iris),0.60*nrow(df))
nrow(df)
```

Console:

```
 > train<-sample(1:nrow(df_iris),0.60*nrow(df))
    Error in sample.int(length(x), size, replace, prob) : 
      invalid 'size' argument
    > nrow(df)
    NULL
```

There is nothing called "df" that can be calculated and passed to the "size" parameter. The calculation could not be done and the "size" parameter was missing. This caused an error.